# Is it normal for User Manager to be started and stopped for UID 0 many times during startup?

Tags: boot, root, systemd, log, session

I'm getting errors on every startup related to User Manager for root (UID 0).  My system is working fine overall, but with an array of very minor, merely annoying idiosyncracies, so I don't know if these errors are indicative of an actual problem, and I can't find much on line to explain what they may indicate.

My system particulars:

```
$ sudo inxi -b
System:    Host: LABUNTU Kernel: 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: N/A Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: Dell (portable) product: Precision 3520 serial: *******
           Mobo: Dell model: 0C7J6P v: A00 serial: /*******/**************/
           Bios: Dell v: 1.6.4 date: 09/12/2017
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-7440HQ (-MCP-) speed/max: 899/3800 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 591b
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           tty size: 80x24 Advanced Data: N/A for root
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM driver: e1000e
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath10k_pci
           Card-3: Atheros
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (44.4% used)
Info:      Processes: 233 Uptime: 2:24 Memory: 2363.9/7865.9MB
           Client: Shell (sudo) inxi: 2.2.35
```

I have noticed a fail alert fly by in the startup log every time I boot up for quite a while, and I finally looked at the logs today:

```
$ sudo journalctl -b0 --system _COMM=systemd | grep "Failed "
Nov 23 09:19:44 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 0.
```

And:

```
$ systemctl status -l user@0.service
● user@0.service - User Manager for UID 0
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 23 09:19:44 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
Nov 23 09:19:44 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 0.
Nov 23 09:19:44 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
Nov 23 09:19:44 LABUNTU systemd[1]: user@0.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 23 09:19:44 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 0.
Nov 23 09:19:44 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 0.
Nov 23 09:19:45 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
Nov 23 09:19:45 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 0.
Nov 23 09:19:45 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
Nov 23 09:19:45 LABUNTU systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 0.
```

So, I looked up the "Start request repeated too quickly" message, and it appears from what I found that this happens when the service is started and stopped too many times within a short time frame (more often than dictated by system settings).

What I can't seem to find is any information on whether (or how to figure out if) this is generally indicative of an actual problem.  I would hazard a guess that it is maybe to do with a badly written service or app being initialized at startup, but I am not basing that on info I found - it's just a guess.

Any info or advice anyone can offer on whether this is anything to worry about, and/or ideas for narrowing down the actual problem, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [old forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/507701-From-var-log-messages-What-is-this-about) mentions it being related to cron, but I see something similar every minute, without any cronjob setup :(